# Experience of non self

Tags: theravada

When experience a cittarupa understand arise if no thoughts come regarding  them self  will  disappears. What is that experience?

Comment: What do you mean by "self will disappear"?

Comment: No craving no clinging

Comment: Your question is too broad.add more info

Comment: Understood  if no thoughts arises regarding cittarupa they will disappear automatically self will not create. No thoughts come out experience no self

Comment: Is that nonself

Comment: Craving a d clinging are just craving and clinging. They are not a self

Comment: Just  because of self that craving and clinging arise

Comment: Not! Craving arise due to ignorance. What you call 'self' is merely an ignorant notion.

Comment: What is an ignorant notion

Comment: Are you asking about the idea of a self or an independent observer?

Comment: The realisation of the enlightened pnes is that there is no self. Therefore it is not the case that some self disappears. The "self" was never there to begin with- but the ignorance which makes one think that what appears is the case- that ignorance disappears. How does ignorance disappear- with wisdom accumulated through cultivation of the right view.

Answer (score 1):

Cittarupa is awareness without reflection: the body-mind at peace. It is sensing everything sensed without assigning value to it. The experience is *composure*, because the illusions that pull the mind and body in various directions are stilled for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Citta-Rupa simply refers to resp. the mind and the body. According to the Abidhamma, this is the everyday human experience where [Citta conditions Rupa](https://www.wisdomlib.org/buddhism/book/abhidhamma-in-daily-life-ashin/d/doc3195.html). What you are referring to as "self will dissapear" is called *nirodha samapatti*, as detailed in the Abidhamma. It refers to a state of Nirvana while still living in Samsara.

To attain Nirvana, the Abidhamma refers to a specific Citta called Cuti-Citta, this is the mental precognition of physical death:

> Even though there is a single nibbana as its nature, nibbana is talked
>   to have two different forms, saupadisesa nibbana and anupadisesa
>   nibbana. Saupadisesa nibbana is nibbana when sattas are still in the
>   samsara are when they are alive. This nibbana is only present in
>   arahats or anagams while they are in **nirodha samapatti. Nirodha means
>   disappearance and samapatti means to be in a state of**. Anupadisesa
>   nibbana is the state immediately after cuti citta of arahats.
>
> Immediately after cuti citta of arahats, there is no more kammaja
>   rupa, cittaja rupa and aharaja rupa. That state from the sattas just
>   gone to nibbana is said to be the state of nibbana called anupadisesa
>   nibbana as there is no trace of so called satta that is no citta, no
>   cetasika, no kammaja rupa, no citta rupa, and no aharaja rupa. Utuja
>   rupa just left is like other bahiddhika rupa and not attached to any
>   satta. So such nibbana is a complete and absolute peace. This is the
>   state all Buddhists are trying to attain after their paccima bhava or
>   final life .

Note that in Theravada Buddhism Nirvana without residing in Samsara can only be attained upon physical death. In Mahayana Buddhism, this "requirement" is eliminated, though many Mahayana traditions still refer to the moment of enlightenment as "The Great Death".